# PowerShell: Foreach for array in Where-Object to verify match on property

Tags: powershell, foreach, where-clause

Good day,
it´s a little hard to explain what I want to do, for that reason I did added code what I´m looking for.

```
$IDFilterList = @("1" , "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
   
    if ($file.Name.Contains("SomeStuff")) {
        $ImportendCollection += $Result | 
        Where-Object { ($_.Level -Match 1) -or ($_.Level -Match 2) -or ($_.Level -Match 3) |
        **** Where-Object { foreach ($id in $IDFilterList) {($_.ID -Match $id)}} |
        Group-Object -Property id, LevelDisplayName, LogName -NoElement | 
        Sort-Object -Property count -Descending
    }
```

I know that this code isn´t correct in the line with the "stars", but it should explain what i want to do.
How must this line be look like correctly?

```
  Where-Object { foreach ($id in $IDFilterList) {($_.ID -Match $id)}} |
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to test whether `$IDFilterList` contains the value of `$_.ID`?

Comment: Since we have no clue what the variables `$file`, `$ImportendCollection`, `$Result` etc. are about, this would be very hard to answer. Please edit your question and tell us what it all means

Comment: Looks like you don't actually need `-match`: `Where-Object {$_.Level -in 1,2,3 -and $_.ID -in $IDFilterList }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this was perfectly what i was looking for and it works like a charm! How can i flag it as "solution"?

Comment: @Larry That's great! I've posted a proper answer below, click the checkmark on the left of it to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case you don't actually need to nest `Where-Object` - since you're looking for exact matches, you might as well use the `-contains` or `-in` operators:

```
... |Where-Object { $_.Level -in 1,2,3 -and $_.ID -in $IDFilterList }
# or
... |Where-Object { 1,2,3 -contains $_.Level -and $IDFilterList -contains $_.ID }
```

---

For reference, the `.Where()` extension method is often a good tool for nesting filter clauses - it works just like `Where-Object`, but it supports different filtering modes, including it's `First` mode which provides for "early exit" once a match is found:

```
... |Where-Object {
        # assign ID property value to local variable
        $ID = $_.ID
        # Test whether any entries in $IDFilterList is a matching pattern for $ID
        $IDFilterList.Where({ $ID -match $_ }, 'First').Count -gt 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. It looks like to me that powershell is much more similar to C# than i thought. Your post is exactly what i was looking for and works how you expected!